# How to set ID of records in sqlite to position/id of Navigation Drawer item

Tags: java, android, sqlite, navigation-drawer

I have 2 array that fetch from 2 column of my table in `sqlite` database.

`1 - Group ID`

`2 - Group Name`

I want create `Navigation Drawer` with Group name that when user click on each item I can get `Group ID` from position/id

```
final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor crs = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE ID != 1",null);
    String[] array = new String[crs.getCount()];
    String[] arrayID = new String[crs.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("GroupName"));
        String id = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        array[i] = uname;
        arrayID[i] = id;
        i++;
```

Now I have 2 array but I don't know how can I set in Navigation Drawer

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, final long id){
```